# Do I need to add all the frameworks from my static library?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries, target

I have an xcode project (project A) that use another project configured as a static library (project B).
In the target section of the project A, I configured the project B as a target dependency, and I add the static library in Link binary with libraries. Also I add the path of project B in the header search paths.

The project B uses a lot of different frameworks from CocoaTouch. If I don't add these frameworks in the project A I got this error

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from
```

If I add them I got no problems.
Is there a way to don't need to add these frameworks? As to mantain all the frameworks in both projects is a difficult task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must satisfy all the dependencies, framework or otherwise, of the static library.

This is because a static library is a simple archive of object files, so you need to think of them as equivalent to the object files of your binary ("Project A" in your case).

Comment: The project B is a library I use in all my projects, and it uses more than 20 frameworks, so every time I add a new framework in my library I need to add in all my projects. Is there any way to manage this easily?

Comment: @balkoth Sorry, I've only just seen your message.  No, I don't think there is an easy way to manage this I'm afraid.